# How to paste from Putty to OneNote with colors?

Tags: putty, copy-paste, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, rtf

Putty has an option to copy to clipboard in RTF format. This means console colors preserved in pasted text. This works ok in MS Word, but does not work in Microsoft OneNote.

Why?

Is it possible to paste with colors from Putty to OneNote?

P.S. Text copied from MS Word is pasted with colors to OneNote.

**UPDATE**

Putty HAS RTF copy option:

[image]

Please, note, that the verys same text looks different if pasted into Winword or OneNote:

[image]

So, this is the problem of OneNote unable to accept RTF from Putty.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem possible.  I have researched this before, as well.  After doing a few google searches, it looks like several others have tried to do the same thing (from other applications) without success.

References:

- [Microsoft forum question/answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/onenote-rich-text-formatting-paste-loss/53f84156-58d0-41ab-905b-76e21c98bd76)
- [Microsoft bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/onenote/feedback/details/412511/no-support-for-pasting-rtf-text-with-formatting)

Your best bet is to do what your are doing now: using Word as a middle-man.

Comment: But why it does not work? Is Putty RTF bad or something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to paste into Word, then copy/paste into OneNote?
For syntax highlighting, try [NoteHighlight](http://notehighlight.codeplex.com/)