# How can I copy Chrome's formatting of XML with Ctrl+V or otherwise?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, xml, text-formatting

If I open an XML file in Chrome, I get a nice visual. I want to somehow copy this formatting to other programs like OneNote. It never copies the format/color though. Anything I can do to get it?  Maybe even an extension if necessary?

**What I see in Chrome and want to copy:**

[image]

**Or even this from SO would be nice:**

```
<Node something="meh">
    Insides http://weblink.com
    <Indented>Super cool</Indented>
</Node>
```

But I always get a dumb string: `<Node something="meh">Insides http://weblink.com<Indented>Super cool</Indented></Node>`

Comment: Your asking for us to recommend a Chrome browser extension.  I suspect half your problem is that OneNote doesn't have a copy formatted text option (or more specifically Chrome doesn't consider that content you are copying to be formatted).  I wasn't personally able to recreate the bad behavior, i copied the XML content into a text file, dragged and dropped into Chrome and copied the XML content into a separate text file and it was formatted.

Comment: That was an option. Is that a problem? Another option is maybe there are settings somewhere. And yes, OneNote does accept (and copies) formatted text. Sounds like you're saying it the wrong way.

Comment: Questions seeking Chrome extensions are likely to be closed as out of scope.  There are specific Stack Exchange communities dedicated to providing software recommendations.  After I changed the file extension of the file to .XML, I was able to recreate the situation, determined that while Chrome is handling the XML content as XML content.  What you are copying isn't actually formatted.  *I was able to preserve the spacing and whitespace, by pasting in a .txt file, and dragging that into Chrome.*

Comment: Notice that the indention isn't being copied [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dhmF.png), that is the reason its being copied as a single line into OneNote, although in my own tests were NOT a single line (event with "keep text only")

Comment: So other possibilities could be things like "view source and copy from there" (doesn't work, unfortunately) or use Developer tools and do something. I expect there's a way to do this without extensions, but I wouldn't mind an extension doing the job.

Comment: I would blame OneNote's seemingly lack of [RTF](https://superuser.com/questions/452462/how-to-paste-from-putty-to-onenote-with-colors) content handling

Comment: It doesn't paste into Word either and Word even usually let's you paste HTML just fine. Also, from word to OneNote works fine. I paste formatting all the time. It just seems like XML in particular is not copying any formatting for some reason. Not from IE either. I just want the darn formatting in OneNote somehow, darnit!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do if no one has any secrets or workarounds!

https://www.prettifier.net/xml/

Comment: I'm afraid that is the only answer. What Chrome displays is not the source data and what you copy/paste is the source.